# How do I nest a PHP array or Laravel collection recursively based on matching values?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm using Laravel version 5.1 (don't ask why), so this data is actually a Laravel collection, but it doesn't matter if this issue is solved by converting it into an array.

Let's say I have this array/collection:

```
$foo = [
    ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'Electronics', 'parentId' => 0],
    ['id' => 2, 'title' => 'Clothes', 'parentId' => 0],
    ['id' => 3, 'title' => 'Computers', 'parentId' => 1],
    ['id' => 4, 'title' => 'HP', 'parentId' => 3],
    ['id' => 5, 'title' => 'Men', 'parentId' => 2],
    ['id' => 6, 'title' => 'Women', 'parentId' => 2],
];
```

So it's an array only containing other arrays, which are related through `id` / `parentId`

What I want to achieve, is to turn `$foo` into an array which is nested based on the `parentId`. Something like this:

```
$foo = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'Electronics',
        'parentId' => 0,
        'children' => [
            [
                'id' => 3,
                'title' => 'Computers',
                'parentId' => 1,
                'children' => [
                    ['id' => 4, 'title' => 'HP', 'parentId' => 3]
                ]
            ]       
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'Clothes',
        'parentId' => 0,
        'children' => [
            ['id' => 5, 'title' => 'Men', 'parentId' => 2],
            ['id' => 6, 'title' => 'Women', 'parentId' => 2]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I've tried `$foo->groupBy('parentId')`, but it only keys the objects with similar `parentId` and also removes the parent data.

Comment: And your attempt at coding this, can you show us that please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$foo = [
    ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'Electronics', 'parentId' => 0],
    ['id' => 2, 'title' => 'Clothes', 'parentId' => 0],
    ['id' => 3, 'title' => 'Computers', 'parentId' => 1],
    ['id' => 4, 'title' => 'HP', 'parentId' => 3],
    ['id' => 5, 'title' => 'Men', 'parentId' => 2],
    ['id' => 6, 'title' => 'Women', 'parentId' => 2],
];
              
function buildTree(array &$elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parentId'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[$element['id']] = $element;
            unset($elements[$element['id']]);
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
var_dump(buildTree($foo));
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you